# CMBright for math and Iwona for text?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

Is there a way to load packages Iwona and CMBright so that Iwona is used only for text, CMBright only for math, and all text and math is sans-serif?

The only command I've thought of so far are:

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{iwona}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
```

And it's certainly not quite right.
Thanks in advance to anybody who shall try to help me.

P.S. I can provide complete code if anybody feels it's gonna be useful.

ETA:

Here's some basic document from which we can try to solve my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
    \section{A section}

    \begin{equation}
        S\!\left(x\right) = \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right] \qquad \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right) = \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right).
    \end{equation}

    \noindent \lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

ETA:

We're almost there. The last thing that remains is the sections, subsections, and so forth font that is ultra bold and ugly, and as far as I know unrelated to Iwona. Is this a thing we can remedy? As for the body's font, I'd like the sections font to be Iwona's sans-serif... Thanks again!

ETA:

I think I found something really interesting for that last part:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\Large}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection {subsection}{1}{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\large}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection {subsubsection}{1}{\z@}%
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize}}
\makeatother
```

Somehow, that really seems to do it, so now if anybody has time for it, I'd would like to understand (even if only a little bit more) why mixing fonts like I did isn't a good idea. I promise to do my best to be open-minded about the semantic problem it engenders.

ETA:

OK, took some time to do more testing, and my last solution wasn't quite right after all. I have nonetheless been able to redeem myselft (at least I think) with teh following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \title{MY TITLE}
    \date{}

    \maketitle

    \section{A section}

    \section{Another section}

    \subsection{A subsection}

    \subsubsection{A subsubsection}

    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            S\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
            H\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
        \end{aligned}
        \qquad
        \begin{aligned}
            \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right)\\
            \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

    \noindent \lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

It has everything I wish for: sans-serif font, sans serif math, no ugly ultra bold sections font. The key is the package sfmath which does an amazing job.

That said, I would appreciate to be noticed if there somehow remains a ticking bomb hidden inside the document.

I would like to thanks anybody who tried to help me, especially cfr. Thank you mate. I mean it (it is very sad that my rep prevents me from upvoting you).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Iwona has an accompanying math font set, why would you use CMBright for math?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Note that this doesn't mean giving the 'complete code' where that means *your* whole document. Rather, it means creating a small, complete document just as an example.

Comment: I want to use CMBright because I don't like the way some symbols look like with Iwona (e.g. 'S'). THis is silly I know, but then again, if it is possible, why not at least try?

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code from you document so that you include just enough to reproduce the issue. I doubt that the mix of fonts is affected by the fact that you are using a paper size peculiar to North America or that your document is hyperlinked with fancy headers, for example.

Comment: Cleaned the code as most as I dared. Hope this works for everybody here.

Comment: @RSMax That is not a good solution. You are not really using Iwona except for the large maths symbols. The only reason you are not getting bold section headings is because `iwona.sty` changes the default bold series to `b` and this series is not defined for Computer Modern. Except for large maths symbols, you are using the default Computer Modern fonts but selecting everything from the sans family. That's fine but it will get very confusing later if you mistakenly believe that you are doing something else!

Comment: By the way, I don't think you are mixing fonts badly. You just believe that you are mixing fonts which would be bad to mix. However, since you aren't actually mixing them, what you are doing is not bad. [At least, not bad for that reason. You might be doing excellent typography for nefarious ends. But that would be a different issue and off-topic for this site!] Although typesetting a whole document in sans is not usually recommended but it does depend on the document. It might not be good for a book but it might be for a presentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In no way do I recommend doing this as I think it is aesthetically extremely dubious, at best. However, this site is not concerned with whether things are typographically judicious but only with the most technically elegant implementations of them in TeX.

`iwona` sets the font up as the default roman family. `cmbright` sets up the font as the default sans family and then sets the default family to sans.

So, if we load `iwona` first, we can let `cmbright` overwrite the maths configuration, which will fall back to `iwona`'s choices for e.g. `OMX` wheere these are not provided by CM Bright. (This is not a good idea but it seems to be what you have in mind.)

We can then switch the default family back to roman to obtain Iwona for text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      H\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
      &\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      &\\
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right).
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

  \noindent
  \lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Iwona and CM Bright]

See `cmbright`'s documentation for suggestions concerning suitable large symbols, such as `cmex`. These may go a bit better than mixing Iwona. But, since you are already mixing two sans fonts, perhaps large symbols are the least of your worries.

You should also consider a solution which involves replacing just the symbols you do not like. There are several questions of this kind on the site to use as guides.

## EDIT: NOTES

If you use the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      H\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
      &\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      &\\
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right).
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

  \noindent
  \lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

then you will get CM Bright for text ***and*** maths. The only exception is the large maths symbols, lacking from CM Bright, which will come from Iwona:

[image: CM Bright with large Iwona maths symbols]

I think in that case, you might be better off dropping Iwona altogether and using the configuration suggested in `cmbright`'s documentation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      H\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
      &\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right)
      & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      &\\
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right)
      & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right).
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

  \noindent
  \lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

[image: CM Bright and CM Extended for large maths symbols]

## UPDATE

This is a response to the edited question. As I explain in a comment, the solution posted there is not a good one because it is not really doing what you think.

Let's start by examining the different fonts because this is causing some confusion:

[image: font sampler]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  Default Computer Modern Roman (serif):

    \lipsum[1]

  \sffamily Computer Modern Sans Serif:

    \lipsum[1]

  \fontfamily{cmbr}\selectfont Computer Modern Bright:

    \lipsum[1]

  \fontfamily{iwona}\selectfont Iwona:

    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I gather from comments, that you do not actually like Iwona. That is, you do not want to use the last font in the sampler above. This is not 'Iwona serif' or 'Iwona roman'. It is just Iwona. If you don't like that font, you don't like Iwona.

### Computer Modern Sans

What you wish to use, I think, is either Computer Modern Bright or Computer Modern Sans Serif. The code I gave earlier demonstrates how to use CM Bright. To use Computer Modern Sans Serif:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: cmss]

The complication in all this is that `iwona.sty` installs Iwona as the default roman/serif family even though Iwona is actually a sans serif font. So, if you load `iwona` but then switch to sans for the document, you don't actually see any Iwona in use for text at all. (Unless you explicitly request the roman family.)

I think what you really wish to do is to use the large maths symbols from Iwona to avoid the serif versions you otherwise get. And I'm not sure that is the best solution. However,...

### Maths

What happens to maths? By default, nothing. All we've done is change the text font. As you explain, `sfmath` can be used to activate sans maths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      H\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right)\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: sans maths]

This is taking large symbols from Computer Modern's `cmex` font, with letters and operators from the sans serif font.

### Large Symbols from Iwona

If you would prefer to take the large symbols from Iwona, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sfmath}% use cm, cmbright or lm as options for similar maths fonts (cm is default)
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% take large maths symbols from Iwona as these aren't available in Computer Modern for sans (otherwise we get serif symbols from cmex)
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}  {OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{iwona}{b}{n}
\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      H\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right)\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Sans with sans maths and Iwona large symbols]

### Iwona, Bold and Computer Modern

The issue of bold sections is different. What happens if you load `iwona` is that it redefines the bold series

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
```

So the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sfmath}% use cm, cmbright or lm as options for similar maths fonts (cm is default)
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% take large maths symbols from Iwona as these aren't available in Computer Modern for sans (otherwise we get serif symbols from cmex)
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}  {OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{iwona}{b}{n}
\begin{document}

  \textbf{bold} and normal text

\end{document}
```

will produce this:

[image: disabled bold]

That is, you cannot use bold at all. This happens because the far-from-ideal redefinition in `iwona.sty` interacts with the far-from-ideal default setup of the Computer Modern fonts. In fact, the manual for `sfmath` recommends loading `fix-cm` and doing so before `\documentclass`. Adding

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

before `\documentclass` fixes the problem:

[image: reinstate bold]

So loading `iwona` merely to get non-bold sections is also going to kill bold everywhere. But fixing bold will also reinstate bold sections because if LaTeX can find bold fonts, it will use them for section headings by default. Moreover, it is likely to lead to inconsistencies in surprising places. It would be better to *ask LaTeX for non-bold sections* rather than hoping that LaTeX will be unable to find bold fonts at all.

### Non-Bold Sections

The `titlesec` package can be used to achieve this easily. The following passes `titlesec` the `sf` and `md` options for sans serif, medium weight section headings. [Note that the options are `sf` and `md` rather than `sffamily` and `mdseries` i.e. they do not correspond to the LaTeX font commands `\sffamily` and `\mdseries`.]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% recommended in documentation for sfmath
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sfmath}% use cm, cmbright or lm as options for similar maths fonts (cm is default)
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% take large maths symbols from Iwona as these aren't available in Computer Modern for sans (otherwise we get serif symbols from cmex)
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}  {OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{iwona}{b}{n}
\usepackage[sf,md]{titlesec}
\begin{document}

  \section{A section}

  \section{Another section}

  \subsection{A subsection}

  \subsubsection{A subsubsection}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      S\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \mathsf{Pr}\!\left[X > x\right]\\
      H\!\left(x\right) & \ = \ \int_0^x h\!\left(t\right)\mathsf{d}t\\
    \end{aligned}
    \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
      \widehat{S}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \textsf{exp}\!\left(-\widehat{H}\!\left(t\right)\right)\\
      \widehat{H}\!\left(t\right) & \ = \ \sum_{k \, | \, t_k \leq t} d_k / n_k
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sans, medium sections, sans maths and text, large symbols from Iwona]

Importantly, this preserves your ability to use bold when you wish:

```
\textbf{bold} and normal
```

[image: bold and normal preserved]

Note that even if you do not wish to use bold, loading `iwona` to get rid of it is not a good solution because some fonts (such as Iwona) *do* have a bold `b` series and you are likely to get weird things happening. Moreover, your logs and output on the console will complain frequently about missing fonts, making it harder to identify real issues which you do want to find.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a clue as to why and how combining Iwona and CMBright isn't a good idea, but I'll trust you on that, otherwise I wouldn't be asking questions in the first place.

Also, can we use Iwona's sans-serif font or are we stuck with roman? I highly dislike Iwona's roman font.

Comment: Got it, replaced rmdefault with sfdefault.

Comment: @RSMax If you replace `rmdefault` with `sfdefault`, you get CM Bright for text. Iwona does not have a roman/serif family. `iwona` just sets up Iwona as the default roman family (even though it is not serif). At least, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RSMax It is not generally a good idea to mix two serif or two sans fonts in the same document except for limited uses or if you really know what you are doing. (I don't really know so I try to avoid doing it except for the use of e.g. special effect fonts.) In the case of maths, it is usually best to use the same/complementary fonts when possible. This isn't always possible but consistency is the aim. However, you are, I think, basically using CM Bright throughout and, while the use of sans for an entire document would be bad in e.g. a paper, that is hopefully not your case.

Comment: @RSMax Please see my edit for notes on this.

Comment: To be honest, I can't differentiate the text fonts from the last to pieces of code... damn, maybe it was all in my head. The sum symbol in that last piece doesn't work for me though. Anyways, thanks a lot. See my last edit for more info.

Comment: @RSMax The text in the last two is the same. That is the point. The only difference is in the large maths symbols.

Comment: @RSMax Please see my updated question. This explains how to get non-bold sections, sans text and maths, everything from CM except for large symbols from Iwona, and how to preserve your ability to use `\textbf{}` or `\bfseries` should you wish to do so. But it is a better solution even if you don't care about bold because it should avoid unexpected surprises. Please let me know if you have questions. [By the way, you can accept an answer even if you lack sufficient reputation to upvote. I'm not saying you should accept mine. But you do have the option. Click on the grey checkmark at top left.]

Comment: @cfr Had a similar problem, trying to use `cm` for text and `iowa` for math to get an overall sans-serif document, and used the answer above to achieve it (thanks!). However, in the end I found it was "aesthetically extremely dubious" and so I switched to the [`mathastext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext?lang=en) package, wich was imported after redefining the font.

Comment: @berna1111 Glad my answer helped you, even if you decided not to use it in the end ;).

Comment: The `sansmathfonts` package when loaded with `esint` provides sans-serif sum and integral symbols matching with CM. They'll perhaps match with cmbright as well, although I don't know how to actually achieve this.