# Font issue: missing symbols

Tags: fonts

I want to use the font as given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, amsmath, amssymb, fancyhdr, eulervm}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
\begin{equation}
4+4=8
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but now in math mode symbols as plus (+) and equal (=) are not printed. How can this issue be solved? I noticed that if I would put

```
\usepackage{cmbright}
```

on top then the issue disappears but then also the font type changes, which I do not want.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Welcome! Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203364/cmbright-for-math-and-iwona-for-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete `eulervm`. Now it works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
\begin{equation}
4+4=8
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `lmodern` is useless (but innocuous). +1